# PHP header working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, session, header

this is my php page.. if anyone directly visits this page it will read session if the value is not set then value and redirect to page.html. else it will print some message. this is working on local host but not on live server.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['team']; //a value stored in session which i used on this page  

if (($_SESSION["abc"] !== 'good')) {
    header('Location: http://www.abc.com/page.html');
}
else{
echo $name. 'you have completed register process part one you may continue!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Any errors or warnings?

Comment: no errors it just loads the part 2 of registration instead of redirecting it.

Comment: try using if (isset($_SESSION["abc"])) , there won't be any error then. I hope you get an idea.

Comment: @Neo nope its not working :(

Comment: Unsure if this would help, but try removing the second = on the if (($_SESSION part, so its just != rather than !==

Comment: @user1284164 what if the $_SESSION['team'] is not defined? I think you need to check this too via isset

Comment: @vxstorm nope that is also not working. i read i should use ob_start but i don't feel i like i need that. m not pro in php. can that help me?

Comment: @Neo that is user input in part one and also i am running query in part one on this. so f session exist then it is defined for sure.

Comment: @user1284164 can you elaborate the complete flow so that we can reach the main issue and what was the error on SERVER.

Comment: Need to check the value of $_SESSION["abc"] using echo $_SESSION["abc"]; You should get "good" to redirect.

Comment: Whats the output of `var_dump(session_save_path());`? Does the location exist? Do you have read/write permissions to that location?

Comment: @everyone please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351006/headers-not-working-php

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This


<?php 

session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['team']; //a value stored in session which i used on this page  

if (($_SESSION["abc"] !== 'good')) {
?>
  <script>
    window.location = "http://www.abcd.com/page.html";
  </script>
<?php
}
else{
echo $name. 'you have completed register process part one you may continue!';
}
?>
```