# headers not working PHP

Tags: php, mysql, header

Page 1 abc.html.. on submit it will jump to this PHP page . 
This is page PHP1.php here i am trying to validate user input if name and id in in data he will be forwarded to fill out second part of registration if not it will just give error.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["acb"] = "good";
$_SESSION['team'] = $_POST['team_name'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
if (!$con)
  {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("mydbName");
if(isset($_POST['team_name'],$_POST['id'])){
 $team_name =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['team_name']);
$id =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
if (!empty($team_name)) {
$result= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`teamname`) FROM `table` WHERE `teamname`='$team_name' AND `id`='$id'");    
        $team_result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if ($team_result[0] == '0') { //if does not exist print failed.
            echo 'Varification failed';
        } else {
 header('Location: http://www.abc.com/REGISTERpart2.php');
}} }  ?>
```

RegisterPART2.php is where i am checking my session exist or not (the one i started in last file). if not i want to redirect back to form one and fill that first then come to registration part 2

```
 `<?php
 session_start();
 $name = $_SESSION['team']; //a value stored in session which i used on this page  
if (($_SESSION["abc"] !== 'good')) {
header('Location: http://www.abc.com/page1.html');  //take back to stage 1 coz user did not fill first part.
}
else{
echo $name. 'you have completed register process part one you may continue!';
}
```

?>

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ..that said, what is your question?

Comment: basically everything is working on localhost but as soon as uploaded my code on hosting server nothing works.   also there are no errors. :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the new MySQL version (MySQLi), so the first page will become:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["acb"] = "good";
$_SESSION['team'] = $_POST['team_name'];
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "mydbName");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $con->error());
};   
if (isset($_POST['team_name'],$_POST['id'])) {
$team_name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['team_name']);
$id = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
if (!empty($team_name)) {
$result = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`teamname`) FROM `table` WHERE `teamname`='$team_name' AND `id`='$id'"); 
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($one,$two,$three,$etc);
$result->fetch();
if (empty($one) and empty($two) and empty($three) and empty(etc)) { // may be and/or (pick one)
    echo 'Varification failed';
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.abc.com/REGISTERpart2.php');
}
}
}  
?>
```

Comment: this code is working but now i also want to insert a query into db (i want to all team name in team table). i did this 
    `$into= $con->prepare("INSERT INTO team (team_name) VALUES (($_POST['team_name'])");
    $into->execute();`

Comment: on the next page i am testing if session is continued them print ....
`<?php 
session_start();
 $name = $_SESSION['team'];

if ($_SESSION["abc"] !== 'good')  {
  
echo  'verified but no session found';
}
else{
 echo  ' your ID is verified ';
}
?>`

Comment: the insert one must be:
**$into = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO team (`team_name`) VALUES (?)");
$into->bind_param('s',$_POST['teamname']); /* it's 's' because it's string, learn mysqli::stmt */
$into->execute();**

Answer (score -1):

You may use the following alternative to header.

```
prinf('<script>window.location = "URL HERE"</script>');
```

It should do the same thing as header does.

Comment: He never echoes anything before the headers. They're in a different condition.